# Read logs for last month with logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have configured my logstash config file to read apache access logs like this:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "apache_access"
        path => "/etc/httpd/logs/access_log*"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
  if [path] =~ "access" {

    mutate { replace => { "type" => "apache_access" } }

    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} - %{DATA:username} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)" }
    }

    kv {
      source => "request"
      field_split => "&?"
      prefix => "requestarg_"
    }

  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        host => "10.13.10.18"
        cluster => "awstutorialseries"
    }
}
```

files that i have in the directory `/etc/httpd/logs` are:

```
access_log
access_log-20161002
access_log-20161005
access_log-20161008
access_log-20161011
...
```

When accessing all files in path `access_log*` it can make time if we have a interesting number of archived files.

In the server we rotate logs avery 3 days, so we archive the `access_log` file to be `access_log-{date}` and logstash as the config says, it reads all access_log files in that directory even the archived ones are included.

after some month we are in front of a lot of files that logstash should read so it can make time to read them all.

Q1: Is there a way to read all the logs once, and then just access_log file?

Q2: Is there a way or a custom expression to do in config file to read just some log files deponds on date and not all of them ?

I have tried a plenty of conbinaison and filters on my config file based on official documentation but no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern "access_log*" will match all the old files, too, but logstash will ignore any files older than a day.  See the ignore_older param in the file{} input.  When catching up on old files, you can set this to a higher value.

Once you're caught up, I would release a new config that only looked at "access_log" (no wildcard, this the latest file only).

Comment: I didnt find `older_than` param in file{} input here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html but `ignore_older` yes. Actually this param is about last modified date of a logfile and not last date inside it. Do you know how can i change params to get just last access_log file after getting others whithin a specific date ?

Comment: Yes, it's indeed ignore_older.  I've updated the answer.  If you want to look at the age of each entry inside the file, you'll need to do that with a ruby filter to compute the age and then drop the event if it's outside of what you want.